# How read Doc or Docx file in java?

Tags: java, doc

I want to read a word file in java

```
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.HeaderStories;

import java.io.*;

public class ReadDocFileFromJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**This is the document that you want to read using Java.**/
        String fileName = "C:\\Path to file\\Test.doc";

        /**Method call to read the document (demonstrate some useage of POI)**/
        readMyDocument(fileName);

    }
    public static void readMyDocument(String fileName){
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

            /** Read the content **/
            readParagraphs(doc);

            int pageNumber=1;

            /** We will try reading the header for page 1**/
            readHeader(doc, pageNumber);

            /** Let's try reading the footer for page 1**/
            readFooter(doc, pageNumber);

            /** Read the document summary**/
            readDocumentSummary(doc);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  

    public static void readParagraphs(HWPFDocument doc) throws Exception{
        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        /**Get the total number of paragraphs**/
        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
        System.out.println("Total Paragraphs: "+paragraphs.length);

        for (int i = 0; i &lt; paragraphs.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Length of paragraph "+(i +1)+": "+ paragraphs[i].length());
            System.out.println(paragraphs[i].toString());

        }

    }

    public static void readHeader(HWPFDocument doc, int pageNumber){
        HeaderStories headerStore = new HeaderStories( doc);
        String header = headerStore.getHeader(pageNumber);
        System.out.println("Header Is: "+header);

    }

    public static void readFooter(HWPFDocument doc, int pageNumber){
        HeaderStories headerStore = new HeaderStories( doc);
        String footer = headerStore.getFooter(pageNumber);
        System.out.println("Footer Is: "+footer);

    }

    public static void readDocumentSummary(HWPFDocument doc) {
        DocumentSummaryInformation summaryInfo=doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation();
        String category = summaryInfo.getCategory();
        String company = summaryInfo.getCompany();
        int lineCount=summaryInfo.getLineCount();
        int sectionCount=summaryInfo.getSectionCount();
        int slideCount=summaryInfo.getSlideCount();


    enter code here
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("Category: "+category);
        System.out.println("Company: "+company);
        System.out.println("Line Count: "+lineCount);
        System.out.println("Section Count: "+sectionCount);
        System.out.println("Slide Count: "+slideCount);

    }

}
```

http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/java-and-docx-format/

**I want to read a doc or docx file in Java**

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here.  Without further detail, this question is likely to be closed.  What is your goal (viewing, processing, editing, printing)? What have you tried so far?  What isn't working?  Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 28):

Here is the code of ReadDoc/docx.java:  This will read a dox/docx file and print its content to the console. you can customize it your way.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = null;
        WordExtractor extractor = null;
        try
        {

            file = new File("c:\\New.doc");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
            extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
            String[] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++)
            {
                if (fileData[i] != null)
                    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exep)
        {
            exep.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to do something with that exception.

Comment: in this case word extractor can only gives the text of the doc file.
it even does not mention where the paragraph is starting or ending...

Comment: What about the content apart from text(Image, Bar code,..). Can you please edit the code further to read complete data?

Comment: is ther any way to know page number throug offset with this method?

Comment: This only works in pre 2007 Office.