# Read details property from DOCX

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

How I can read property->details->(title | subject | comments) from *.docx document.

Comment: With help of Apache POI.

Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102511/how-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java

Comment: it can not help me because it for docx only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document metadata is common across .docx, .pptx and .xlsx formats, so any tutorial or example for reading metadata from any of those formats will do you just fine. Apache POI has everything in it you need.

One great example of reading OOXML metadata is [POIXMLPropertiesTextExtractor in Apache POI](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/POIXMLPropertiesTextExtractor.java), I'd suggest you read through that code to see how it works.

Comment: Also see Apache Tika