# Reading .docx file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I am trying to read one file in java, following is the code :

```
public void readFile(String fileName){
        try {
        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); 
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine()) != null ){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        }catch (Exception ex){}
            }
```

It is working fine in case of txt file. However in case of docx file, it is printing weird characters. How can i read .docx file in Java.

Comment: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) seems to be the most common library used to read Microsoft file formats.

Comment: That is certainly true for Excel (.xls and .xlsx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How read Doc or Docx file in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102511/how-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java)

Comment: `.docx` files are not plain text files, which have a file extension of `.txt`; and they are encoded differently. You would need an API to read it, as suggested by @jahroy above.

Answer (score 14):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
    public void readDocxFile() {
            try {
                File file = new File("C:/NetBeans Output/documentx.docx");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

                XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

                List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();


                for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
                    System.out.println(para.getText());
                }
                fis.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Internally **.docx** files are organized as zipped **XML**-files, whereas **.doc** is a **binary** file format. So you can not read either one directly. Have a look at **docx4j** or **Apache POI**.

If you are trying to create or manipulate a .docx file, try **docx4j**
[Here is the source](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)

or go for apachePOI

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read the docx file or doc file directly. You need to have an API to read word files. Use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/. If you get any doubts, please refer this thread on stackoverflow.com
[How read Doc or Docx file in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102511/how-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

you must have following 6 jar:

1. xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
2. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
3. poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
4. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
5. poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL.jar
6. poi-3.5-FINAL.jar

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
 
public class test {
 public static void readDocxFile(String fileName) {
try {
File file = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

for(int i=0;i<paragraphs.size();i++){
    System.out.println(paragraphs.get(i).getParagraphText());
}
fis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
 readDocxFile("C:\\Users\\sp0c43734\\Desktop\\SwatiPisal.docx");
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile. paragraphs is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I had more complicated docx file and these solutions with `document.getParagraphs()` wasn't working. What works in my case was:

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
...
protected List<String> readDocxFile(String fileName, Path path) {
    XWPFWordExtractor xwpfWordExtractor = null;
    try (var doc = new XWPFDocument(Files.newInputStream(path.resolve(fileName)))) {
        xwpfWordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
        var docText = xwpfWordExtractor.getText().split("\n");

        return Arrays.asList(docText).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(String.format("Can not read file %s.", fileName));
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } finally {
        if (xwpfWordExtractor != null) {
            try {
                xwpfWordExtractor.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.info("Not able to close xwpfWordExtractor.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I used these maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```