# Store values from a text file into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, io

I need to read a `txt` file and check if the text file has "First Name". If it contains, it should split the line and display the line in the console.

```
public String[] getFullname() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\main\\resources\\CV.docx"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("Full Name")) {
                String[] fname = line.split(":");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fname));
                firstname = fname;
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return firstname;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample input and problem you are facing?

Comment: Uh, a `docx` file is most definitely not a text file. First, you'll have to unzip it, then, find the correct file within the zip archive that contains the text, then, parse that file (xml), and then check for the text you're looking for. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you haven't actually asked a question. You say that you "need to read a `txt` file and check &c." Okay, you need to do that. What's the problem?

Comment: Also also, why are you catching `FileNotFoundException` *and* `IOException`? An `IOException` *is a* `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Thanks @DavidConrad

Answer (score 1):

1. You are comparing **First Name** with **Full Name**. That's why the `if` condition fails.

   Use

   ```
   if (line.startsWith("First Name"))
   ```

   Instead of

   ```
   if (line.startsWith("Full Name"))
   ```
2. Use `contains` instead of `startsWith` if you want to check if the line has the word **First Name**. 'startsWith' only checks if your line's starting characters match with your string.

   ```
   if(line.contains("First Name")){
    // your logic 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to docx file. There is apache poi API which is used for reading files written using MS Office suite products. I have tried it once for excel files. The way you are doing it, is valid for text files.

First you can check logging content of file on console. If you are able then only you can check it starts with something.

Please refer to the answer posted here for reading docx files:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543577/4940369

Please also correct "Full Name" with "First Name".

Logic used seems incorrect as well:

split() method returns array of strings separated by character/string delimiter. firstName is not declared anywhere in this block. You are trying to assign array to String. You can use substring(line.indexOf(':')) something.

It will always return the name found in last line which starts with "First Name". There is no break or something. firstName variable will be reassigned each time when line starts with 'First Name'. You can use list instead of Array, if want to return each first name. Keep adding them in list as they found.

Answer (score 0):

> *...check if the text file has "**First Name**"...*

In your code you are searching for *Full Name* instead of *First Name*.

Replace

```
if (line.startsWith("Full Name")) {
```

with

```
if (line.startsWith("First Name")) {
```

---

**UPDATE**:

As David has mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454287/store-values-from-a-text-file-into-an-array-in-java/51454482#comment89878464_51454482), if you are trying to read a Word document. Your attempt is completely useless.

Comment: @Dharshan nice to see someone from SL btw. :)

Comment: Changed the document type and it worked fine for me. Thanks bro :)