# Opening and reading a Word document in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying the code below to open and read a Word file in `JTextArea`, using Netbeans.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = null;
        WordExtractor extractor = null;

        try {
            file = new File("c:\\New.doc");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
            extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
            String[] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
                if (fileData[i] != null)
                    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception exep) {
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error below:

```
cannot find symbol : HWPFDocument((mypackgename).fileinputstream )
```

Due to this, I can not open the file.  Is there a reason that this isn't working?

Comment: 1- your post and code suggest that you would like to read a pdf file. Yet you're feeding your code a word document **File = new File("c:\New.doc");**

Comment: 2- your code suggest you're using a 3rd party library: **Apache POI-HWPF**. Are you sure you have that library in the classpath of your netbeans project?

Comment: Possible duplicated -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102511/how-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java

Comment: @sgmart:  **The code from the linked "duplicate" is a 1:1 copy.**

Comment: It's a copy but not a duplicate. It's copied from an an answer to the linked question (and possibly a wrong answer, since that question was about reading a word document and not a pdf file).

Comment: Thing about this question:  It *mentioned* reading a PDF document, but the code used to ask the question only concerned itself around Word documents.  I leave it to the OP to clarify if they want to read either a PDF, a Word document, or both.

Comment: @Makoto: yes I agree with you there, hence my first comment.