# What is the practical Usage of Bytes stream to character streams

Tags: java

What is the practical use of the below code for binary files- convert bytes streams to character streams:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("E:\\Users\\17496382.WUDIP\\Desktop\\jio.doc");
InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF8");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ir);
String s;
while((s=br.readLine())!= null){
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Well, here is a fact:  the data storage format for a Word document is full of metadata that describes the document to the Word software.  In order to fully decode a Word document, you need to do one of the following: 1) use a library that can decode the storage format and present it to you in a form that is easier for you to work with; or 2) find documentation on the storage format and write your own custom file stream.

Comment: There is no documentation on MS Word format.  This is closed source protected by copyright laws.

Comment: tx. what is the practical usage of InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF8");  (what exactly bytes stream to character streams is done here)

Comment: @Senthil You can read text files using that approach. Try using Windows Notepad to save a text file using UTF-8 format. You should be able to decode it with your code snippet above.

However, the code snippet cannot decode files which are not text files. It can for example not decode `.jpg` files or `.doc` files.

Comment: tx for the response, If it is just text files, I can directly use FileReader to read the files (if I want to use character set, then use NIO Buffered reader to mention the character set). Not able to understand under what scnerio I should use - InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF8");

Answer (score 0):

word document consists of binary meta data in addition to the text. You can plainly see this is you try to open the file with notepad. You need a library like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102511/how-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java) how to correctly read MS Word document

Comment: huh?? did you look at the links?

Comment: Yes I did. Have modified the original questions. Tx for your response

Comment: you don't understand. there is no way to read MS Word doc via a Java InputStream. You have to use a library like the one i mentioned in the answer. period.

Comment: what is the practical usage of InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF8"); (what exactly bytes stream to character streams is done here)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you say that there is little value in opening a `FileInputStream` and using a `InputStreamReader` on it to allow it to be used as an instance of `Reader`. You can just as easily open the file using `FileReader`.

If I understand your question, you are asking "what is the use of `InputStreamReader`?" The short answer is that there are many, many other instances of classes that extend `InputStream` besides `FileInputStream`. If you needed a `Reader` and all you had was an instance of `InputStream`, then you would wrap it with an `InputStreamReader`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html for some classes that extend `InputStreamReader`.

(None of these have any bearing at all on the ability to read a Microsoft Word file, however.)

Comment: ok, you mean...for ex-  when we have urls as inputstream and want to read it on screen , we can use inputstreamreader and read it using readers

Comment: Some things work with byte streams, some work with character streams. Sometimes you need to convert from one to the other. That's pretty much all there is to say about it.